# Keyboard outputting wrong characters

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, logitech-keyboard

I have a compact Logitech 811 keyboard today i cleaned it with a towel i pressed many keys doing so and now i get wrong output from it like so

```
3 = u3  
u = u3  
t = -t  
y = 'y  
' = 'y  
m = mz  
x = 9x  
z = mz  
a = nothing at all  
- = -t  
9 = 9x  
backspace does not work
```

I tried restarting, repairing via bt and checked kb settings.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows seems left right keys have also been remaped

Comment: Try the keyboard on another computer.  Try another keyboard on your computer.  Any change?

Comment: Did you try removing and reinstalling the keyboard batteries?

Comment: @Steven tried and its same.

Comment: @SterlingDuchess Which way did you try: another keyboard or another computer?

Comment: @Steven i paired it with pc and tried typing

Comment: I have the same issue. Scared me when my password stopped working!  Did you just replace it?